# HttpPost failed due to "Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity"

Tags: android

I tried to upload a photo to a server by HttpClient in android mobile, but sometimes I get this error, it not happens always. anyone know how to solve it?

my code like:

```
HttpClient client =new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut httpPut = new HttpPut(uploadUrl);       
InputStream in =null;
HttpResponse response =null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(filepath);
            BasicHttpEntity entity = new BasicHttpEntity();
            entity.setContent(in);
            entity.setContentLength(new File(basepath+path).length());

            httpPut.setEntity(entity);
            response = client.execute(httpPut);
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());


            consume(response.getEntity());


        }
```

.......

Error info:

```
11-22 10:32:50.370: W/System.err(15224): org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
11-22 10:32:50.370: W/System.err(15224):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
11-22 10:32:50.370: W/System.err(15224):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-22 10:32:50.370: W/System.err(15224):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-22 10:32:50.370: W/System.err(15224):    at com.hp.nimbus.android.skydrive.util.SkyDriveUtils_Rest.doUploadPhoto(SkyDriveUtils_Rest.java:203)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at com.hp.nimbus.android.skydrive.util.SkyDriveUtils_Rest.uploadPhoto(SkyDriveUtils_Rest.java:250)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at com.hp.nimbus.android.skydrive.FolderMonitorService$1.onEvent(FolderMonitorService.java:36)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.onEvent(FileObserver.java:125)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224): Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:419)
11-22 10:32:50.380: W/System.err(15224):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-22 10:32:50.390: W/System.err(15224):    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Hi, thanks your reply. I tried FileEntity before, the problem is that the upload server doesn't support the FileEntity, I have to use FileInputStream. And you mentioned the initial request failed, Is it able to know the reason for this failure?

Comment: Not supporting `FileEntity` sounds odd. For a simple fix, try wrapping your entity within a BufferedHttpEntity - this will make it repeatable but chew through a bit more memory doing so.

Answer (score 6):

It means the initial request failed, and because it's a stream it can't repeat it.

If you remove the `FileInputStream` and instead use [`FileEntity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html), I believe it will be repeatable.

You also won't have to set the length.

Answer (score 2):

Might be a little late to answer this question, but for people who land on this page, the reason for the exception is `BasicHttpEntity` does not allow repeatable requests. You will need to use the proper `HttpEntity` implementation.

For the case of this question, it will be `FileEntity` as Matthew Flaschen mentioned in the other answer, but for most of the other cases, [StringEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.2.x/current/httpcore5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/core5/http/io/entity/StringEntity.html) can be used which allows repeatable requests.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when it is trying to send request more than once. Since its a stream, it can not repeat it.

You can try to buffer the input stream.

```
BufferedHttpEntity bhe = new BufferedHttpEntity(new InputStreamEntity(in));
httpPut.setEntity(bhe);
```